# How can I get NetworkManager to autoconnect to a Openconnect VPN via nmcli without prompting for a user and password

Tags: network-manager, vpn, automation

I am trying to set up a script driven VPN connection with nmcli on Lubuntu 12.10 using Openconnect and NetworkManager and I cannot seem to get it to connect either with the saved credentials or via sudo with

```
[vpn]
....
password-flags=0

[vpn-secrets]
password=your_password
```

as I've seen suggested many places.

Any ideas on how to bypass the connect dialog?

Comment: Have you looked into `openconnect` CLI with `vpnc-scripts`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've installed openvpn, if not start with install :

Just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install openvpn
```

then you should Edit /etc/default/openvpn.

so issue this :   `sudo gedit /etc/default/openvpn`

then Uncomment the AUTOSTART="all" line.

[image]

these steps are issued from this link : [Starting OpenVPN client automatically at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464264/starting-openvpn-client-automatically-at-boot)

save and close.

If a username/password is required,

edit the .conf file

edit auth-user-pass user-password-filename

Create a file containing:

```
username
```

> password

save and close. reboot your system.