# How to enter password on console with NetworkManager's nmcli

Tags: networking, network-manager, password, vpn

I want to connect to a VPN with `nmcli`. Is there a way to allow me to provide a password to `nmcli` from the console?

There seem to be ways to store the password in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/<connection>`, [that I don't seem to be able to get working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/444866/how-to-save-vpn-passwords-with-networkmanger-for-nmcli). But I'd prefer not storing passwords in files at all.

On the desktop I enter the password every time, but when I run `sudo nmcli con up id MyVPN` over SSH, it *opens a GUI dialog on the remote desktop* asking for my password, which seems like a strange design decision to me. If I *had* e.g. VNC to the remote desktop, I wouldn't use `nmcli`...

Answer (score 10):

Try using the `--ask` flag:

```
nmcli --ask con up id MyVPN
```

I've dropped `sudo` because it is probably unnecessary (and dangerous).

Comment: I just tried `--ask ` which is in Ubuntu 15.04. If I run this from a console over ssh, then the dialog asking for the password *still* appears on the *remote* desktop, not where I can see it in the ssh session. :-( If I had access to the remote desktop, I wouldn't need `nmcli`

Comment: works for me.
@PeterV.Mørch to get this working over ssh i also had to add poltik rules.

Answer (score 2):

this should work on ubuntu 16.04:

```
nmcli --ask con up id MyVPN
```

to get this working over **ssh** i also had to add rules in

```
  /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/90-mandatory.d
```

one called `90-ssh-network-control.pkla` with content:

```
[Network Manager - Control network nmcli]
Identity=unix-user:yourusername
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.network-control
ResultAny=yes
ResultInactive=yes
ResultActive=yes
```

and another called `90-ssh-own-network.pkla` with the same except for the Action field, replace with:

```
Action=org.freedesktop.NetworkManager.settings.modify.own
```

on 14.04LTS the `--ask` option is not available.