# Network manager not saving vpn password

Tags: kubuntu, network-manager, password, vpn

Ive been running Kubuntu 19.10 for some time now and today I tried to setup protonVPN with it. All went well however when I tried to connect it asked me for my password which I had just saved.

Turns out my network manager doesn't save the password when set to save for this user only. Is there any solution to this or is this a known bug?

Comment: Does it work if you save it for all users?

Comment: Have the same problem with Windscribe VPN.  This only started with 19.10, versions before have worked well.  Have it saved for all users, but am only user.  My password was re-entered a few minutes ago and is  missing again now.  Do have box show up for password when connecting, but usually it be hidden behind other windows unless I look for it.

Comment: My VPN password is saved in 'passwords and keys' and unlocked after login, but still not automatically login to VPN.

Comment: I have this issue on ubuntu 20.04 + kde too. just `store for all users` work.

Answer (score 1):

I was googling around and found this,  by clicking on the little icon in password field it seems to keep password.  Do not know yet if it will automatically login to VPN. Here is the link and am using second answer.   [Can't save VPN passwords in Network manager (Xubuntu 16.04)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/899754/cant-save-vpn-passwords-in-network-manager-xubuntu-16-04) 
Have tried connecting to VPN, and it is logging automatically now without having to type password.  Use the 'store for all users' option.

Comment: yes this worked for me. Ubuntu was not only blanking out the password I had put in, then making a new connection without any vpn, then frequently disconnecting and reconnecting. store for all users works. ubuntu 20.04.1 and usb ethernet adapters

Answer (score 0):

have the same problem and could not fix it, yet.

Please note: I'm talking about kubuntu 19.10 using vpnc. The solution which I use works fine with kubuntu 18.04.

So hints as in the link above do not help because in 19.10 (as int 18.04) a drop down menu is used where I try to use "Store password only for this use (encrypted)" (please note: I have a German install, so this is my translation of what I see in German) which (as already mentioned) works in 18.04 but does not do its job in 19.04.

I can use "Store password for all users (not encrypted)" which stores the password in 19.10 but as the label says the secret information is stored unencrypted in the conf file which is not what one would want to have.

So it would be more than helpful, if this bug would be resolved.

Comment: Sorry, meant to say "... but does not do its job in 19.10."

Comment: Comment below does not help on my side. The password is not stored what ever I do want to store the passwords for my router at home in an non-encrypted manner. Its annyoing that I always have to connect to my home router first to retriev the shared secret (the password for the user is not that much of a problem, this I can remember because I have to use it for login).

Comment: Ok, finally, I found the problem. Settings are inconsistent in 19.10. If in the VPN (vpnc) tab of the network manager (I'm talking about kubuntu and I only guess that this is the network manager interface) one selects "Passwort für diesen Benutzer speichern (verschlüsselt)" (I'm using German as interface language and do not want to guess the official translation), in the "Allgemeine Einstellungen" tab the switch "Alle Benutzer dürfen sich mit diesem Netzwerk verbinden" remains active(!!!) which is of course inconsistent. When I switched this off, the passwords were stored. Finally!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm running network-manager 1.10.6 and I'm having this issue. Applying changes to your connection's password *after* it's been created and saved for the first time will not have any effects. From my tests it seems that once the VPN is set the first time it won't change the password anymore, blank or not.

What worked for me is the following:

1. Delete the connection that refuses to store the password.
2. Import the `.ovpn` file. Accept when it asks to copy the certificates.
3. Select the newly created VPN entry. Copy the username and password from the website, don't try to copy the credentials from other servers you've configured in Network Manager. **Do not change this view because if you do Network Manager will refuse to save the password.**

From then on your password should be saved. For future reference, I'm also storing the password encrypted.

Answer (score 0):

This bug was fixed in the package network-manager - 1.20.4-2ubuntu2.2

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager/+bug/1858092#fromHistory