# Does Nordvpn really have an app ithat works on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS?

Tags: 20.04

Nordvpn app install fails on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I successfully installed the repo's and the .deb. When I go to the terminal to login (first time)  It redirects to a link and then asks which application to open it? any pointers? Is there really an app at all? I can login ok using the terminal but what a pain to use terminal every time I wish to change servers or connection protocol.

Comment: That is a question for NordVPN not here.

Comment: Sounds like Nordvpn app is a third party app for Ubuntu, that would make it on-topic on AU.

Comment: installing nordvpn deb package , sudo apt update , sudo apt install nordvpn, then nordvpn login, then it gives you a link to login using a browser (which is a bit daft as you would be without a vpn at that stage). so highlight that link then ctrl-alt-c to copy to clipboard and paste into browser, or choose the browser to open it as per that prompt. alternative is nordvpn login --legacy to do it in the browser.
the deb package seems to just put the repository info in for an install after update.
I am on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS still though.

Comment: note I had a hell of a problem with ubuntu 'forgetting' my vpn password. the trick is using nm-connection-editor , where the password goes, which Ubuntu blanked out for me, there is an icon to save the password for all users. that seems to have done the trick. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1202930/network-manager-not-saving-vpn-password

Comment: major news, new NordVPN Version 3.14.2  works for me in terminal . you might need to uninstall ( see other related threads here)  though I did not. hell of a time this year (and earlier) with unbuntu/gnome network manager method, which frequently decided to connect a new ethernet connection without vpn, also asking for password when it was set ok before. I hope this lasts. clonezilla backup imminent.....