# Starting OpenVPN client automatically at boot

Tags: startup, openvpn

I'm trying to get OpenVPN to start automatically at boot. Today I have to manually type in

```
sudo openvpn --client --config $HOME/openvpn/anonine.ovpn --ca $HOME/openvpn/anonine.ca.crt
```

followed by username and password. Is there a good way to make this automatic at boot?

Answer (score 50):

Edit `/etc/default/openvpn`.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo gedit /etc/default/openvpn
```

Uncomment the `AUTOSTART="all"` line.  Save and close.  Reboot your system.

[image]

Comment: (i) How can one start a specific VPN that way? (ii) Who supplies authentication for a connection initiated in this way (can it initiate connections without the username-password combination being stored in plain text)? (iii) If possible, cli methods are preferable (allows implementation on a headless server). I can substitute `nano` for `gedit`, but I can't use nm-applet to store credentials in the keyring.

Comment: @JonathanY. Take a look at these available resources, [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VPNClient), and [Here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN).  You may also want to consider asking a new question.

Comment: Much obliged. As far as I can tell the answer to (i) (which is well within the scope of this question) is that `AUTOSTART="all"` attempts to start every `.conf` file in `/etc/openvpn` (I'd love to have confirmation, though). An answer to (ii) is also reasonably scoped withing this question--you can't automatically initiate a VPN connection unless the secrets are available without user input (keychain being preferable to plain-text for obvious reasons). I admit that (iii) is extracurricular and might well merit a new question. None of them are answered in these links, that I can see, though.

Comment: As the comment in the picture states, the default for AUTOSTART is actually "all". This edit is consequently not needed, in my opinion.

Comment: @YvesB Default is "all" only when AUTOSTART is uncommented and empty

Comment: systemctl daemon-reload instead of reboot

Answer (score 15):

If you're on systemd (16.04) , configured AUTOSTART="all" and it's still not starting pay attention to this:

```
> # If you're running systemd, changing this variable will
> # require running "systemctl daemon-reload" followed by
> # a restart of the openvpn service (if you removed entries
> # you may have to stop those manually)
```

Just do a

```
systemctl daemon-reload
```

and then restart the service

```
 sudo service openvpn restart
```

Comment: how do you specify the `.ovpn` ?

Comment: @DimitriKopriwa just rename `.ovpn` to `.conf`.

Answer (score 11):

You can put `auth-user-pass filename` in your `anonine.ovpn` where `filename` is the file with username/password on 2 lines.

Make sure that `filename` is properly secured, because it will contain plain username/password.

This is from `openvpn --help`:

```
Client options (when connecting to a multi-client server):

--auth-user-pass [up] : Authenticate with server using username/password.
                  up is a file containing username/password on 2 lines,
                  or omit to prompt from console.
```

You also can add your certificate to your `anonine.ovpn` adding it this way:

> ```
> <ca>
> -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
> -----END CERTIFICATE-----
> </ca>
> ```

Answer (score 6):

If a username / password is not required in order to connect, then rename the .ovpn files to have an extension of .conf.

OpenVPN should connect on boot, even without autostart=all.

If a username/password is required,

edit the .conf file

edit auth-user-pass user-password-filename

Create a file containing:

```
username
password
```

If you want to connect with Network Manager, make sure you first do:

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
```

Make sure your Ubuntu is at least 14.04. This doesn't work on 12.04.

If you don't have your ca.crt, client.crt, etc, extract them from .conf.

With Network Manager, create a new VPN connection or import your conf.

Add the certificates and ta.key.

Routes, use connection only for resources on its network.

Edit your Internet connection with network manager. Choose **connect with VPN**, then choose your VPN connection.

Answer (score 1):

While it might not be of interest to the OP, I was frustrated by this service not starting until login--either graphical, or one of the Ctrl+Alt+F# TTYs. I eventually realized that my machine would only connect to wifi when I logged in. Combining the other answers here with the standard advice to run `sudo update-rc.d openvpn defaults`, and with the first answer at [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16376/connect-to-network-before-user-login) worked for me. Perhaps this might help another Googler.

Comment: `eventually realized that my machine would only connect to wifi when I logged in.` Same issue here!

Answer (score 0):

For me the

`auth-user-pass filename`

did not work

use

`askpass /etc/openvpn/filename`

And only have the password on the top line

It worked and now openvpn starts at boot

commands to check if openvpn is working:

`systemctl status openvpn@"your vpn user name"`

`wget -qO- http://ipecho.net/plain ; echo`

to check your ip (it must be different than the external ip of your router)

`sudo service openvpn stop`

`sudo service openvpn start`

to check your config without rebooting all the time.