# Ubuntu 16.04 auto-start VPN

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn

I had a daemon starting with my own self-hosted vpn that worked fine with:

```
sudo openvpn --config /home/philip/open_vpn/client1.ovpn
```

Now that I changed to a paid VPN service the above works but requires me to manually enter my credentials each time. This means my auto-start breaks.

Looking at the GUI for network manager it seems I can make any individual network auto-connect to the vpn, but unknown networks are the most important time for me to use vpn.

How can I get the auto-vpn to work without entering my email and password every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how I got it working. In my folder with all my vpn ovpn files I create a file called `auth.txt`. Which contained the following, *substituted for my actual credentials*:

```
Username
Password
```

I then opened up the ovpn file I wanted to use, and found the line with `auth-user-pass` I modifying it to look like this, *replace path with full path of your auth.txt file*:

```
auth-user-pass /home/philip/open_vpn/auth.txt
```

I then made a bash script called `start_vpn.sh` which looks like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo openvpn --config /home/philip/open_vpn/nord/ca24.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn
```

I then create a systemd startup script at `/etc/systemd/system/start-openvpn.service` which looks like:

```
[Service]                                                                                                                                             
ExecStart=/home/philip/open_vpn/start_vpn.sh                                                                                                          

[Install]                                                                                                                                             
WantedBy=default.target
```

I then enable the systemd job with:

```
systemctl enable start-openvpn.service
```

---

**Bonus:**

If you have 100s of ovpn files like me you may want to update the line in all these files at once. Here is the `sed` command I used in the folder with my ovpn file, *you will nedd to update to reflect your system*:

```
sed -i *nordvpn* -e 's/auth-user-pass/auth-user-pass \/home\/philip\/open_vpn\/auth.txt/g'
```

Answer (score 1):

The first, You edit file `vim /etc/default/openvpn` and uncomment the `AUTOSTART="all"` line. Save and Reboot your system.

[image]

And you can read more link: [Start Openvpn client automatically at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464264/starting-openvpn-client-automatically-at-boot)