# disable keychain for vpn connection?

Tags: network-manager, vpn, openvpn, keychain

To begin with, please be patient and keep answers fairly simple, I'm a Linux quasi-noob. But I'm a sysadmin and can usually figure stuff out, but this issue is foiling me.

I use an Ubuntu 16.04 home theater pc to run Kodi. It's set up to auto-login and auto-start kodi upon boot. This mostly works pretty well. But I've signed up for a vpn and trying to incorporate the openvpn connection into the process without user input is seeming impossible?

1. I've installed openvpn and openvpn-gnome, and set up the vpn connection. It works fine using the credentials.
2. I've set the main wired connection to automatically connect to the vpn when it launches. This is where the issue is. It prompts for the keychain password. And it doens't even try to connect unless I tell it to.
3. I've tried the solution here: https://blog.matthewurch.ca/?p=331 but it didn't work.
4. I don't know enough to try something like [Ubuntu 16.04 auto-start VPN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/948817/ubuntu-16-04-auto-start-vpn), I'm missing some info on how to set that up, and not sure if it would work if I could.

I understand that the default is for the keychain to engage with auto-login. Is there no way around it? I also don't want to use a blank keychain password since that will send my vpn password unencrypted (as I understand it).

To clarify, my goal (if possible) is: 1-autologin, 2-connect to vpn, 3-launch kodi, all with no user input.

Any help is appreciated.