# How to auto(re)connect to openvpn connection?

Tags: networking, network-manager, vpn, gui, openvpn

I've got an openvpn connection set up, which I basically always need to use. Is there a way to always make it connect whenever there is an internet connection?

Answer (score 3):

Edit /etc/default/openvpn. Just press Ctrl+Alt+T on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

> sudo gedit /etc/default/openvpn

then Uncomment the AUTOSTART="all" line.

[image]

these steps are issued from this link : [Starting OpenVPN client automatically at boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/464264/starting-openvpn-client-automatically-at-boot)

save and close.

If a username/password is required,

edit the .conf file

edit auth-user-pass user-password-filename

Create a file containing:

> username

```
password
```

save and close. reboot your system.

Comment: But if the connection is dropped and later restored, will this make it reconnect?